# .htacces file and MAMP

Tags: codeigniter

I have installed MAMP on my laptop and moved my web project (developed using CodeIgniter) under MAMP's webroot.
I use an .htaccess file to hide my index.php file within my urls and everything is working fine...almost, everything.
I'm able to surf my site locally as in my remote server but some folders/files are not recognized. Looks like they are missing or the path is not matching the physical location on my laptop.
Basically I have configuration like below:

```
MAMP
htdocs
    myFolderSite
        .htaccess
        site
            myApplicationFolder
                .htaccess
                config
                controllers
                views
                .....
                ...
            myPublicFolder
                css
                images
                .....
                ...
```

Surfing my site locally css and images are not visible. All the required files are present under the proper folders within myPublicFolder.
The .htaccess file I'm using in myFolderSite appears as below

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /myFolderSite/
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|upload|users|thumb|fckeditor|public|css|js|robots\.txt|sitemap2\.xml)
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

Am I missing something?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Where's your system folder and main index.php file? Also, I see two .htaccess files in your directory structure, but neither one of them looks like it's in the right place (it should be in the same folder as your index.php file).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The CodeIgniter wiki has a good article on [Mod Rewrite](http://codeigniter.com/wiki/mod_rewrite) that is worth looking at. Specifically, these two lines will stop actual files and directories being redirected.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

I've used this across a few different servers and Macs, without too many problems, so hopefully it helps.

Comment: Finally it's working:) I have added these two lines as you have mentioned, then I have removed the line "RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|upload|users|thumb|fckeditor|public|css|js|robots\.txt|sitemap2\.xml)" and I have also removed the .htaccess file in my subfolder myApplicationFolder. Thanks